# "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeNotConnectedException: [elasticsearch-master-1][10.244.5.215:9300] Node not connected",

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

Today my elastcisearch cluster is down ,I am tryiing to start elasticsearch 7.x in kubernetes cluster v1.16.0, but the log shows like this:

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:25,764Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "no plugins loaded" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:34,174Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "parsed [0] roles from file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:35,372Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[controller/167] [Main.cc@110] controller (64 bit): Version 7.7.1 (Build e5ebdcb44d66cd) Copyright (c) 2020 Elasticsearch BV" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:36,849Z", "level": "DEBUG", "component": "o.e.a.ActionModule", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "Using REST wrapper from plugin org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:37,159Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.d.DiscoveryModule", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:39,066Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "initialized" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:39,066Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "starting ..." }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:39,361Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.t.TransportService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "publish_address {10.244.2.224:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:40,198Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.b.BootstrapChecks", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:40,259Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.c.Coordinator", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "cluster UUID [DpxAr8dDTie2ECKjkxZnhg]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:40,563Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.TransportService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "Transport response handler not found of id [1]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:40,578Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.TransportService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "Transport response handler not found of id [2]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:41,080Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.c.JoinHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "failed to join {elasticsearch-master-1}{O_PxV4tjQuO3C3YeL2Dq5A}{B7er4U65RZy47roWattBRw}{10.244.5.215}{10.244.5.215:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true} with JoinRequest{sourceNode={elasticsearch-master-0}{aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA}{0F8hNLrISlOwJS4wwAD2LQ}{10.244.2.224}{10.244.2.224:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}, minimumTerm=12, optionalJoin=Optional[Join{term=13, lastAcceptedTerm=12, lastAcceptedVersion=331, sourceNode={elasticsearch-master-0}{aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA}{0F8hNLrISlOwJS4wwAD2LQ}{10.244.2.224}{10.244.2.224:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}, targetNode={elasticsearch-master-1}{O_PxV4tjQuO3C3YeL2Dq5A}{B7er4U65RZy47roWattBRw}{10.244.5.215}{10.244.5.215:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}}]}", 
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeNotConnectedException: [elasticsearch-master-1][10.244.5.215:9300] Node not connected",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.ClusterConnectionManager.getConnection(ClusterConnectionManager.java:189) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.getConnection(TransportService.java:642) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:597) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.JoinHelper.sendJoinRequest(JoinHelper.java:284) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.JoinHelper.sendJoinRequest(JoinHelper.java:217) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.JoinHelper.lambda$new$2(JoinHelper.java:141) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler$1.doRun(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:257) [x-pack-security-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler.messageReceived(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:315) [x-pack-security-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:63) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundHandler$RequestHandler.doRun(InboundHandler.java:264) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:692) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]"] }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:41,149Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.c.JoinHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "failed to join {elasticsearch-master-1}{O_PxV4tjQuO3C3YeL2Dq5A}{B7er4U65RZy47roWattBRw}{10.244.5.215}{10.244.5.215:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true} with JoinRequest{sourceNode={elasticsearch-master-0}{aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA}{0F8hNLrISlOwJS4wwAD2LQ}{10.244.2.224}{10.244.2.224:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}, minimumTerm=12, optionalJoin=Optional[Join{term=13, lastAcceptedTerm=12, lastAcceptedVersion=331, sourceNode={elasticsearch-master-0}{aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA}{0F8hNLrISlOwJS4wwAD2LQ}{10.244.2.224}{10.244.2.224:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}, targetNode={elasticsearch-master-1}{O_PxV4tjQuO3C3YeL2Dq5A}{B7er4U65RZy47roWattBRw}{10.244.5.215}{10.244.5.215:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}}]}", 
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeNotConnectedException: [elasticsearch-master-1][10.244.5.215:9300] Node not connected",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.ClusterConnectionManager.getConnection(ClusterConnectionManager.java:189) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.getConnection(TransportService.java:642) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:597) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.JoinHelper.sendJoinRequest(JoinHelper.java:284) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.JoinHelper.sendJoinRequest(JoinHelper.java:217) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.JoinHelper.lambda$new$2(JoinHelper.java:141) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler$1.doRun(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:257) [x-pack-security-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler.messageReceived(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:315) [x-pack-security-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:63) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundHandler$RequestHandler.doRun(InboundHandler.java:264) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:692) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.7.1.jar:7.7.1]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]"] }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:41,283Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.s.MasterService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "elected-as-master ([2] nodes joined)[{elasticsearch-master-0}{aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA}{0F8hNLrISlOwJS4wwAD2LQ}{10.244.2.224}{10.244.2.224:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20} elect leader, {elasticsearch-master-1}{O_PxV4tjQuO3C3YeL2Dq5A}{B7er4U65RZy47roWattBRw}{10.244.5.215}{10.244.5.215:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true} elect leader, _BECOME_MASTER_TASK_, _FINISH_ELECTION_], term: 14, version: 332, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{elasticsearch-master-0}{aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA}{0F8hNLrISlOwJS4wwAD2LQ}{10.244.2.224}{10.244.2.224:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]}, added {{elasticsearch-master-1}{O_PxV4tjQuO3C3YeL2Dq5A}{B7er4U65RZy47roWattBRw}{10.244.5.215}{10.244.5.215:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}}" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:41,751Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master node changed {previous [], current [{elasticsearch-master-0}{aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA}{0F8hNLrISlOwJS4wwAD2LQ}{10.244.2.224}{10.244.2.224:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]}, added {{elasticsearch-master-1}{O_PxV4tjQuO3C3YeL2Dq5A}{B7er4U65RZy47roWattBRw}{10.244.5.215}{10.244.5.215:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}}, term: 14, version: 332, reason: Publication{term=14, version=332}" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:41,852Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.s.MasterService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "node-join[{elasticsearch-master-2}{8Pn-L8c5QtSIVwLE4aJoaw}{49bC6if5Q9-bhz5AUoqJWw}{10.244.7.108}{10.244.7.108:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true} join existing leader], term: 14, version: 333, delta: added {{elasticsearch-master-2}{8Pn-L8c5QtSIVwLE4aJoaw}{49bC6if5Q9-bhz5AUoqJWw}{10.244.7.108}{10.244.7.108:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}}", "cluster.uuid": "DpxAr8dDTie2ECKjkxZnhg", "node.id": "aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:41,859Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "publish_address {10.244.2.224:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}", "cluster.uuid": "DpxAr8dDTie2ECKjkxZnhg", "node.id": "aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:41,859Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "started", "cluster.uuid": "DpxAr8dDTie2ECKjkxZnhg", "node.id": "aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:42,123Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "added {{elasticsearch-master-2}{8Pn-L8c5QtSIVwLE4aJoaw}{49bC6if5Q9-bhz5AUoqJWw}{10.244.7.108}{10.244.7.108:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=2147483648, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}}, term: 14, version: 333, reason: Publication{term=14, version=333}", "cluster.uuid": "DpxAr8dDTie2ECKjkxZnhg", "node.id": "aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:43,571Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.l.LicenseService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "license [e1a503a5-8d9f-45aa-a41b-f477d51b734d] mode [basic] - valid", "cluster.uuid": "DpxAr8dDTie2ECKjkxZnhg", "node.id": "aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:43,572Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.s.s.SecurityStatusChangeListener", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "Active license is now [BASIC]; Security is disabled", "cluster.uuid": "DpxAr8dDTie2ECKjkxZnhg", "node.id": "aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:43,656Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.g.GatewayService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "recovered [6] indices into cluster_state", "cluster.uuid": "DpxAr8dDTie2ECKjkxZnhg", "node.id": "aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T16:09:53,563Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[filebeat-7.7.1-2020.06.15-000010][0]]]).", "cluster.uuid": "DpxAr8dDTie2ECKjkxZnhg", "node.id": "aRQeyMb1SuugfwEXHTapaA"  }
```

what should I do to fix this problem?

```
[elasticsearch@elasticsearch-master-1 ~]$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 3,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
  "active_primary_shards" : 6,
  "active_shards" : 11,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 1,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 91.66666666666666
}
```

Comment: Your cluster seems to be up, the message you got was during initialization and the election to see which node would be the master, this is normal, and your node `elasticsearch-master-1` joined the cluster as show in the logs. Are you still having any problem?